# Find and prove a necessary and sufficient condition for a Kripke Frame

Tags: modal-logic, kripke-models

I am studying Kripke frames in modal logic and I am trying to understand how to solve the task below (the task comes from a workbook and this particular question lacks a conclusion).

[image]

I know that Kripke frames can be reflexive, irreflexive, symmetrical etc and my first interpretation was that I could prove that the modal formula is valid in Kripke frames if R is one of these. By R I mean the relation in the Kripke frame F = (W, R). But after this I got stuck (I still believe in the approach but do not know how to implement it), does anyone want to help me and discuss possible solutions to the problem?

I also drew a Kripke frame/model where this statement applies for b ($F,b \models$), perhaps one can start from it in the proof?
[image]

Comment: Consider frames whose transition relations are functions.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's translate the statement $\Diamond p\land \Diamond q\to\Diamond(p\land q)$ in words. It says that whenever $p$ is possible and $q$ is possible, then it is possible that $p$ and $q$ at the same time. Since this is a formula that has to hold on a *frame class*, and not just on a *model*, we need this formula to be true regardless of the valuation in a frame from our frame class and regardless of which world we evaluate from (so the forumla must hold in *all* models based on the frame, and in *all* worlds in these models).

Let's investigate when our formula does *not* hold. The formula will be false if it is possible that $p$ and possible that $q$, but not possible that both $p$ and $q$ at the same time. So, suppose that we are in a world $w$, and we can see (at least) two other worlds, let's say $u$ and $v$. Then, let's consider a model $\mathcal M$ based on this frame where $u$ and $v$ have different valuations, for example $p$ could hold only in $u$, while $q$ holds only in $v$. Now, does $\mathcal M,w\vDash \Diamond p\land \Diamond q\to\Diamond(p\land q)$?

What does this tell you about the number of worlds that is accessible from $w$? Does this help you to find a characterisation of the frame class that satisfies $\Diamond p\land \Diamond q\to\Diamond(p\land q)$?